Extract a substring from a character string
My layer contains an attribute whose value is:
<a href='data/PHOTOTHEQUE/1996_mission_13201/a96_m13201_p31-104.jpg' target="photo"><img src='data/PHOTOTHEQUE/1996_mission_13201/vignettes/a96_m13201_p31-104.jpg' width='96' height='96'></a>

I want to create another field with the calculator to extract the value: a96_m13201_p31-104.jpg
Can we extract it with a regular expression?

Yes, you can extract it with a regxp. What have you tried so far?

In your example there are two HTML elements that reference a96_m13201_p31-104.jpg.  Although both elements reference the same name/value, they don't have to, so you should be clear in the question whether you are interested in the href or img element (or possibly both).
Assuming the img element is what the question is about, the following regular expression should work:
regexp_matches(
    "HTML_FIELD",
    '<img src=[\'"].*\\/(.*?)[\'"]'
)[0]

A couple of comments regarding the expression:

Although single quotes are given in the example HTML, double quotes are acceptable and common, so the expression should account for both.
Although the example contains a JPG file, there are lots of image file formats, so it is best to avoid using '.jpg' in the expression since the image source may be another format.

